# Removing CSS file that doesn’t exist in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, divi-theme

I tried to install a plugin for divi icons, But it wasn’t installed successfully.

There is a CSS file added to the homepage https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/aspengrove-icons/multicolor.css?ver=1.1.1

That CSS file doesn’t exist and I want to remove it, But I don’t know where it’s added.

How to remove this from homepage:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="ags-divi-icons-multicolor-css" href="https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/aspengrove-icons/multicolor.css?ver=1.1.1" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Answer (score 0):

check your wp-content/plugins folder for the folder names as your extension, if there remove it.